Reference on polynomial attached to permutation group
Let $G$ be a permutation group acting on $n$ objects. Let $C(g)$ be the set of cycles of an element $g\in G$, and define $l(c)$ to be the length of a cycle $c$. Now set
$$T(G) = \sum_{g\in G}\sum_{c\in C(g)}x^{l(c)}\\
 = \sum_{h} \left|\textrm{Cl}(h)\right|\sum_{c\in C(h)}x^{l(c)} ,$$
where the sum over $h$ is over representatives of conjugacy classes Cl$(h)$.
Is there a name/prior research on this polynomial? I am in particular interested in a 'pointed version', i.e. $\overline{T}(G) = x \partial_x T(G)$. For the cylic groups, $\overline{T}$ is the reciprocal polynomial of the cycle index polynomial. For the symmetric groups, one recovers a polynomial propertional to a finite geometric series.
I am also interested in `twisted' versions of $T$:
$$T(G,\chi) = \sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)\sum_{c\in C(g)}x^{l(c)}\\
 = \sum_{h}\left(\chi(h) \left|\textrm{Cl}(h)\right|\right)\sum_{c\in C(h)}x^{l(c)}.$$
for $\chi$ a character of $G$.
